# JSON to Array react, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, reactjs

I have json data obtained form my server and i want to put in a list, i already read
[Convert JSON To Array Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601494/convert-json-to-array-javascript)
and [Converting data from JSON to JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206570/converting-data-from-json-to-javascript-array)
but i can't figure out what of all the options can i use in my code my json is like this:

{"response": {"user": [{"username": "", "description": "", "picture_url": "", "name": "",  "phone": ""}]}, "success": true}

and i want to put it on an array like this:

[{username: "",description: "", picture_url: "", name: "",  phone: ""}]

what can i do for this? i already try the answers of this: [Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)

i also try some functions like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i,obj){
                $(arr).append(obj.username+'</br>');
                $(arr).append(obj.description+'</br>');
                $(arr).append(obj.name+'</br>');
            });
```

and this:

```
var results = data;
            var arr = [], item;
            for (var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; i++) {
                item = results[i];
                arr.push({username: item.username, description: item.description, name: item.name});
            }
```

but with the second one dont show anything and dont show any error, with the first one, showme an unespecthed error arr is not defined.

Comment: post your server side script

Comment: Do you need anything more than this? `var user = JSON.parse(responseJson).response.user; var putItInAnArrayLikeThis = [user];`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your JSON is like this as posted:

```
{"response": {"user": [{"username": "", "description": "", "picture_url": "", "name": "", "phone": ""}]}, "success": true}
```

You already have the exact data structure you want at `.response.user`.

So code would be simple:

```
var json = '{"response": {"user": [{"username": "", "description": "", "picture_url": "", "name": "", "phone": ""}]}, "success": true}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var theArrayYouWant = obj.response.user;
```

This doesn't require any transformation at all (other than deserializing the JSON string), you are just extracting a portion of the data structure represented in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In your sever side script the array that will be converted to json should look like this:

```
$array=array("response"=>array(
                                   "user"=>array(array("username"=>"",
                                                       "description"=>"",
                                                       "picture_url"=>"",
                                                       "name"=>"",
                                                       "phone"=>"")),
                                   "success"=>true
                              )
             );
echo json_encode($array);
```

I think in your server side the "user" array format looks like

```
"user"=>array("username"=>"",
              "description"=>"",
              "picture_url"=>"",
              "name"=>"",
              "phone"=>"")
```

Instead of that, "user" array should be nested, like my first example.

```
"user"=>array(array("username"=>"",
                    "description"=>"",
                    "picture_url"=>"",
                    "name"=>"",
                    "phone"=>""))
```

After converting to json using javascript the output will exactly be:

user:[{username: "",description: "", picture_url: "", name: "", phone: ""}]

Comment: i cant modify the server side script